Next js Apache2 Deployed code: page shows index js content on reload
I have a next js project like this:
root page.tsx and a login folder with its own page.tsx.
My dockerfile content is like this:
FROM node:lts-alpine AS build-stage
WORKDIR /next
COPY ./next/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./next ./
RUN npm run build

FROM debian:bookworm-slim AS production-stage

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y install -y apache2 \
    libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 \
    libapache2-mod-shib \
    build-essential \    libaugeas0 \
    vim \
    nano \
    openssh-client \
    lsof \
 && apt-get -y clean \
 && apt-get -y autoremove \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=build-stage /next/out /var/www/html
COPY ./apache2/nextjs_apache2.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/nextjs_apache2.conf

RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf
RUN a2ensite nextjs_apache2.conf
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN a2enmod proxy
RUN a2enmod proxy_html
RUN a2enmod proxy_http
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod actions
RUN ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/access.log && \
    ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/error.log

EXPOSE 80 443 5001

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD  /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND

And the nextjs_apache2.conf file looks like this:
<VirtualHost *:${MY_FRONTEND_PORT}>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
        RewriteRule  ^/api(.*)$  http://my-frontend-web:${MY_FRONTEND_API_PORT}/$1  [P]
        RewriteCond /var/www/html/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/security.txt
        RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</VirtualHost>

The next.config.ts file is:
import type { NextConfig } from "next";

const nextConfig: NextConfig = {
  /* config options here */
  output: 'export',
  trailingSlash: true,
};

export default nextConfig;

When I start the dockerfile and then open the site in a browser, I get the index.js content as expected. I can also go to /login from the index page using a Link that is there in the index page.
But the problem occurs if I try to reload the /login page or try to go to the /login page directly.
In this case, though the link remains as /login, the content that displays changes to the one from the index page.
I am not quite sure what is going on here.
Can someone help?
